# What's the suffient and necessary condition of two Riemann integral equals?

Tags: calculus

We all know that if we change the value of a Riemann-integrable function on finite points, the new function is still Riemann-integrable and the value of Riemann-integral doesn't change. And it doesn't holds for countable points, the Dirichlet function, for example.

However, we can find some examples that if we change the value on countable points and the integrability and the value of integral don't change, the Riemann function, for example.

What I want to know is what's the boundary between them, that is, **What is the sufficient and necessary condition of two function $f,g$ on any interval $[a,b]$, and $f=g$ almost everywhere, and $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^b g(x) dx$?**

p.s. I'm trying to make my description as clear as possible, and plz ask me about anything I'm not clear enough.

Comment: It seems likely that assuming the set is "discrete" is sufficient. Call $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ *discrete* if and only if for all $x \in A$, there exists $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x) \cap A = \{x\}$. I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to saying that the induced topology on $A$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: If f and g are both Riemann integrable and are almost everywhere equal, the integrals will be equal.  The problem cited (Dirichlet function) is that it is not Riemann integrable, only Lebesgue integrable.